# How to bind a especific column in a grid - XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, grid, binding

For example:

```
{Binding ElementName=grid1.Colums[1],Path=ActualHeight}
```

i know it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your binding:

1. grid1.Columns[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285730/wpf-binding-to-grid-column-width) is not a name
2. A column does NOT contain child elements

If you want to bind to a child of a grid you will have to specify the name of the control you wish to bind to or pick the element out of the Children collection of the **Grid**

**EDIT**

Perhaps you meant something different: binding to the column (although binding to the height of a column is similar to binding to the height of the grid...)

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285730/wpf-binding-to-grid-column-width)

And this works in the designer but does not work at runtime:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="col2" Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding ElementName=col2, Path=ActualWidth}" />
</Grid>
```

The best way seems to be to put a panel in the column and bind to the width or height of that control because that one will update the binding.

Answer (score 0):

`ElementName` has to be only the name of the element, everything else goes into the `Path`.

So it would rather be this:

```
{Binding ElementName=grid1,Path=Colums[1].ActualHeight}
```

However that does not make sense if your control is actually a `Grid`, since there is no property called `Columns`, so you might want to use:

```
{Binding ElementName=grid1,Path=ColumnDefinitions[1].ActualHeight}
```

However that still does not make sense since `ColumnDefinitions` do not have a `ActualHeight` property, did you mean `ActualWidth`?