# Binding to actualWidth doesnt work, allthough it works in the designer; wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I wrote an application in WPF and binded the width of an rectangle to the with of a grid columnDefinition.
I filled it red to test if it works. It works in the designer but when I start the application I cant´t see anything red.
That´s my main window:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="col1" Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="col2"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="row1"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" SizeChanged="CanvasChangeSize" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=col1, Path=ActualWidth}"/>

    </Grid>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why are you binding the Width at all? The Rectangle would automatically be resized to the width of the column. Just don't set its HorizontalAlignment to anything else than the default Stretch.

Comment: I don´t know why but it doesnt work too when I delete the width attribute or if I write Grid.Column="0" instead

Answer (score 2):

The Binding is pointless. Remove it, and don't set HorizontalAlignment:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But why does the binding not work?

Comment: ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth is not a dependency property and does not notify about property changes. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/286737/1136211